# use oauth2 for authentication in react web application

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I need your guidance/suggestion on the scenario I am into.
We have a legacy GWT application(version 2.7), this application has 2 controllers which implement EntryPoint class - LoginController and OTSController. These have their respective presenter and viewer.

N.B. - this GWT application runs as a spring-boot application.

This GWT application is a ui application(and there is another spring-boot application which would act as a server app). The GWT app uses default way of handling user authentication i.e. using /j_spring_security_check.

Now I am trying to re-write the Login functionality in React(and I am quite new with React). I am trying to use oauth2 for authentication, can you please point which oauth2 library I should use and is their any sample which I can look into.

I have searched for authentication for React web-app and seen examples for -

1. Okta Sign-In Widget
2. Auth0 - provides authentication-as-a-service
3. Stormpath React SDK
4. JWT(JSON Web Token)

But couldn't find any specific js library that gives oauth2 implementation(and which doesn't have much strict license obligations) that I can use in my react app, please give me pointers so I can use any existing/implement oauth2 authentication for my Login page(using react).

Thanks,
Saurabh.

Answer (score 1):

You can use these two libraries from Okta for integrating authentication into a React app with Okta - @okta/okta-auth-js and @okta/okta-react. You can also checkout the guide here  - https://developer.okta.com/code/react/okta_react. Hope this helps.

Comment: can I just use okta's client(oauth2 client) library in react and configure a oauth2 server of my own? I can see a <Security> tag in examples which have server configurations(as of now pointing to okta's OAuth2 server). Where can I get some details(api doc) on the options I can use with Security tag?